# Difference between "content" and "contentment"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Given this sentence:

> I find (content/contentment) when sitting on a crowded subway train.

or in the sentence fragment:

> my place of (content/contentment)

In the dictionary, I see that *content* (as a noun) means "a state of satisfaction" and *contentment* means "a state of happiness and satisfaction". Therefore I am unsure of which one to use. Does the difference come down to formality or is there a proper use case for each one?

Comment: You might try contrasting *happy/happiness* with *content/contentment*. *"I am happy in my place of happiness"*, *"You are content in your place of contentment"*.

Comment: ...or more relevantly, a few generations ago you might have been *merry* in your place of *merriment*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *contentment*. The sense of *content* as a synonym for *contentment* is no longer in use, except as a component of set phrases like *[my] heart's content*.

The American Heritage Dictionary defines *content* (*n.*) as

> 1. something contained, as in a receptacle.
> 2. individual items in a publication or document; material that constitutes a document.
> 3. a. substance or significance of a work, especially as contrasted with its form.
> 4. The proportion of a specified substance: Eggs have a high protein content.

and finally (with a different pronunciation)

> Contentment; satisfaction.

The **noun** *content* is not often used to indicate the state of being happy.

It is, however, used as an [adjective or transitive verb](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=content) with that meaning, e.g. I am content/he contented himself with one piece of cake.

Comment: OED doesn't explicitly label the older usage "obsolete", but the only modern context that immediately occurs to me is the fixed expression *"to your heart's content"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I see that that OED entry hasn't been changed since first publication in 1893, with the most recent quotation without "heart's" being from 1842. So maybe that sense was still in active use at the time.

Comment: _contentment_ is the right choice for the O.P.'s sentence, but if you change the verb _find_ to _am_, it would be better to use the other noun: _I am **content** when sitting on a crowded subway train._ (As a side note, the O.P. might be interested in [ell.se].)